# Shortcode To Display Post Custom Field Value Inside Excerpt

Tags: custom-field, shortcode, excerpt

I want to create a shortcode that pulls value from a custom field of a post and returns that value inside excerpt.

I already have a function for the custom value:

```
function geo_name_function( $atts ) {

    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'post_id' => get_the_ID(),
    ), $atts, 'geo_name' );

    return get_post_meta( $atts['post_id'], 'field_name', true );
}

add_shortcode('geo_name', 'geo_name_function');
```

And filter for the title:

```
add_filter( 'the_title', function( $geo_name_function ) {
    return do_shortcode( $geo_name_function );
});

add_filter( 'the_title', 'se385007_title_filter', 20, 2 );
function se385007_title_filter( $title, $post_id ) 
{
    $new_title = str_replace( "[geo_name]", "[geo_name post_id=$post_id]", $title );
    return do_shortcode( $new_title );
)
```

I thought that by adding the Excerpt filter:

```
add_filter( 'oceanwp_excerpt', 'do_shortcode');
```

It will fix it but it did not.

I tried adding few other filters but just ended up breaking WordPress ).

At the moment if Custom Value is **Ice Cream**. If my excerpt is **Favorite [geo_name]** it only returns **Favorite**.

Please assist!

Comment: `oceanwp_excerpt` is not a core WordPress hook. This question may require specific knowledge about whatever that third-party product is in order to answer, in which case it might be considered [off-topic](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for our stack. Your best bet may be to pose the question in the product's official support channels.

Answer (score 0):

Even though this is specific for **OceanWP**, the solution is plain Wordpress.

Add these two lines to the end of your `functions.php` to render the shortcodes in both `the_excerpt()` and `get_the_excerpt()`.

```php
add_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'do_shortcode' );
add_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'do_shortcode');
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I tried it, the solution did not work for me. I even tried on several WordPress installations